# Need a MySQL SELECT to Identify Spammers for Deletion

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to delete spammer type users who signup on my website with a PHP snippet added to the user signup script.

I am new to MySQL and need a **SELECT** statement to find users where the values of fid 2 and fid 3 are the same. In some cases the values of fid 2, fid 3, and fid 5 could be the same as shown in the profile_values database table below. In this case, the value **Mollardgasse 42** is the same for fid 2, fid, 3 and fid 5. Therefore this user 4138 will be deleted.

So, if fid 2 and fid 3 are the same or fid 2, fid 3 and fid 5 are the same, I want to identify the users so I can delete them.

I know how to delete the users once the users has been identified but I don't know how to write a select statement to identify the users if the condition(s) above are met.

**SELECT * FROM profile_values WHERE...... ?**

Thanks in advance.

```
fid uid     value
1   4138    Nation
2   4138    Mollardgasse 42
3   4138    Mollardgasse 42
4   4138    4770
5   4138    Mollardgasse 42
6   4138    
7   4138    Female
8   4138    30
9   4138    Significant Other
10  4138    QS
11  4138    LD
12  4138    Associates Degree
13  4138    Just enough to pay bills
14  4138    http://bodyphlo.com/studio-shoes-the-latest-in-fit...
15  4138    
16  4138    
17  4138    0
19  4138    
20  4138    
21  4138    Human
1   4137    usa
2   4137    coolhead
3   4137    kelly
4   4137    555-1212
5   4137    norwalk
6   4137    
7   4137    Female
8   4137    38
9   4137    Significant Other
10  4137    2124 livermore ave
11  4137    California
12  4137    Masters Degree
13  4137    Doing ok
14  4137    http://google.com
15  4137    
16  4137    
17  4137    0
19  4137    
20  4137    
21  4137    Human
```

Comment: Hi there. I notice from your question history that a lot of your questions are "I want X, how do I do it?". I tend to think that the community here at Stack Overflow is quite good at encouraging people to try something first (and to show that in their question). Similarly, you've responded to Dan by saying "it didn't work" but haven't said why you think this is, nor have you tried anything else. Use answers here as clues to get you further to your goal, and be willing to experiment! This will help the learning process much better than just being handed answers.

Comment: I responded to Dan stating that "no results (users) were found" and that's why it did not work. I do not know why it did not work. I am not a MySQL programmer / expert.

Comment: I appreciate you're not an expert, but nevertheless do please consider my advice `:-)`. I'm suggesting a sense of experimentation and a willingness to try things (quite aside from solid study) will help you in the long term. If you can say, in each question, "here is what I tried", then you may end up figuring it out as you ask - which is helpful to the learning process.

Comment: Before I ask for help I do try to figure it out myself to seek a solution. I also search the web for an answer. I only ask for help if I can't find a solution. If I post my test trials that did not work, it may confuse the reader of what I am trying to do, especially if my code is wrong. Therefore, I try to post specifically what I am looking for getting straight to the point, without cluttering up the question with erroneous information. Getting straight to the point may help others with similar questions in the future to get answers without the need to filter through erroneous information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pv1.uid
  FROM profile_values pv1
  JOIN profile_values pv2 
       on pv1.uid = pv2.uid
      AND pv1.fid = 2
      AND pv2.fid = 3
      AND pv1.value = pv2.value
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM profile_values GROUP BY fid, uid, value HAVING COUNT(value) > 1
```

Comment: @Sammy, can you look at your data to see why it didn't work? Perhaps the set of those three values really is unique - differing whitespace?

Comment: No additional white space in the values were found. I checked via phpmyadmin.

Comment: The COUNT(value) > 1 may be the problem. The values to look for are text strings as in the example stated above "Mollardgasse 42".

Comment: COUNT counts the number of found values, not the number of chars in a string or summarizing like `SUM()`. This statement should be grouping all fields with same values having at least 1 duplicate `value`

Comment: The data table may have duplicate data, but the duplicates cannot be in the specific fid's mentioned above. For instance, a user may have the same value for two other fid's, but the spam bots that sign up duplicate the values in fid 2 and fid 3 or in fid 2, fid 3 and fid 5 only.

Comment: `19  4138    
20  4138` <- this is considered spam then ? Or.. just block fid 2,3 and 5 ?